# Using busybox with UBI files system on an MTD flash device, du and df commands give incorrect values

Tags: linux, busybox, flash-memory, ubifs

I have mounted a UBIFS on my MTD partition which is 191.9MB in size.

When I run mtdinfo -a the partition shows:

```
mtd6
Name:  data2fs
Type:  nor
Eraseblock size:  65536 (64KB)
Amount of Erase Blocks: 3071 (201261056 bytes, 191.9MB)
etc...
```

But when I run df -h I get:

```
               size     used    free
ubi2:data2fs   680.2G   20.0K   664.2G
```

Why would this be? - all my mounts are like this (this is just the one I picked for this question).

For a particular file "test.log":

- When I run du -ah on data2fs I get: `4.0K test.log`
- when I do ls -l I get: `test.log 40 bytes` (this is the actual value)

I don't get why ls would work and du /df are giving different results...

**update**

Testing with `stat -f /mnt/data2fs` seems to give the correct answer:

```
Block Size: 4096
Total: 43738 (4096 x 43738 = 170.85MB)
Free: 43732
Avail: 42522
```

These are the figures that I would roughly expect (its not 191MB because UBIFS has a 5-10% overhead).